# When I do JQuery ".html"..this updates the div's innerHTML

Tags: jquery

What if I want to APPEND to it instead of completely replacing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if to append AFTER

> [append](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append)
>
> [appendTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/appendTo)

if to append BEFORE

> [prepend](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prepend)
>
> [prependTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prependTo)

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough there's a jQuery method called `append()`.

```
<div id="x"><em>Hello</em> mum</div>
<button onclick="$('#x').append(' you slag')">Insult please</button>
```

**Don't** use `x.html(x.html()+'something')` or its non-jQuery counterpart `innerHTML+= 'something'` to add content to a document. You will be serialising the current content to HTML, then changing it, then parsing it back into objects. Apart from this being unnecessarily slow, you'll lose any non-serialisable data such as event handlers, JS references and form field values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `+=` string operator.

```
var element = document.getElementById('yourId')/
element.innerHTML += 'More content!';
```

This is without using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(whatever).html($(whatever).html() + string);
```

The above code replaces the content with a combination of the existing content and the value from the `string` variable.